# Error: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1) … When Invoking Methods on a Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I implemented using SOAP Asp. Net 3.5 and VS2013 Express, a legacy system.

There is a web-service running site works perfectly, but when publishing to server generates the error below. What must be wrong?

```
Server was unable to process request. ---> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0272: The property or indexer 'SGR.Modelo.Servicos.IntegracaoMovimentacao.MovimentoDTO.Totalizacao' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible
error CS0272: The property or indexer 'SGR.Modelo.Servicos.IntegracaoMovimentacao.MovimentoDTO.Totalizacao' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible

Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código. 

Detalhes da Exceção: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0272: The property or indexer 'SGR.Modelo.Servicos.IntegracaoMovimentacao.MovimentoDTO.Totalizacao' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible
error CS0272: The property or indexer 'SGR.Modelo.Servicos.IntegracaoMovimentacao.MovimentoDTO.Totalizacao' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why it worked in your working machine and not in production server but for ASp.NET WebServices work they need property getters to be `public`.

```
public string MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

If you have something like this it wont work:

```
public string MyProperty{ get; private set; }
```

This wont work too:

```
protected string MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

Hope it helps.